# Sending a same message to many objects in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, message

I have some objects named object1, object2, object3, and I'd like to send the same message to them with a for loop, instead of :

```
[object1 message];
[object2 message];
[object13 message];
...
[object200 message];
```

Thanks.

Edit : Sorry guys, my question wasn't precise (and maybe my english too...)

I have some objects (more precisely custom buttons) in my interface and the same number of custom views. When i touch a button, it send the same message to the related view.

In the view controller header file, i declared n outlets for my views, and n actions for my buttons.

So my question is : instead of declaring all theses outlets and actions (a lot of copying/pasting and editing...), how can I code just one action, and send the message to the good object.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Then put them in an array instead of calling them `object1`...`object200`.

Comment: Yeah like an array. for( int i=0; i <[array count]; i++){ [[array objectAtIndex:i] message];}

Comment: I hope this is a contrived example, or you have some issues with your code...

Answer (score 3):

You can put them into array and use `NSArray`'s method `makeObjectsPerformSelector:`

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(message)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just throw them into an array:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[object1, object2, ... object200];
```

Then you can either loop through them:

```
for (ClassObject *i in myArray) {
    [i message];
}
```

or easier just use `makeObjectsPerformSelector`:

```
[myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(message)];
```

Comment: Honestly, if the objects are named `object1` through `object200`, chances are that they should be in an array already. If not, OP has a much larger problem than having to send one message to 200 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Register your objects to listen for a [specific `NSNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) sent from an [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Once heard, call your `message` on the object. If all your objects are children of the same parent class, you can set this up in the class definition.